# constructing continuous function with range of rational numbers

Tags: real-analysis, irrational-numbers

Can we construct funtion $f$  non-constant and continuous on $\mathbb{R}$,  $f$:$\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{Q}$.

Is that right "By intermediate value theorem, there exist irrational number between two images of $f$ (say $f$(m)>$f$(n)  where m,n belongs to $\mathbb{R}$) since $f$ is non constant , so that there is no function with these properties."

Answer (score 0):

Intermediate value theorem, not mean value theorem.  And the point is not just that there is an irrational number $y$ between $f(m)$ and $f(n)$, but that there is $x$ with $f(x) = y$.

Comment: So, there is such function.